# Как сделать блоки обновления новостей (dispatch grand central)?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

Подскажите как сделать отправку новостей или статей, комментарии...ЧТоб при обновлении старые данные не меняли на новое время, а оставалось когда она было отправлено.Вот я сделал очередность чтоб сегодня , вчера и дату указывало.Но столкнулся с проблемой что при обновлении старые данные меняли дату на то что только что загрузил.Очень буду благодарен за подсказку.Я посмотрел много уроков, и не могу врубиться что и где указывать.И нужно указывать этот метод везде перед `tableView.reloadData()` и что еще нужно дописывать чтоб происходило действие при парсинге?  очень буду благодарен за статью или помощь в усовершенствовании кода.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let sportCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sportCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell


                if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0  {


                 let insertRow = (soccerString.count - 1) - indexPath.row
                 let soccer = soccerString[insertRow]

                sportCell.matchLabel.text = soccer.matchS
                soccerString[insertRow].imagePrS.getDataInBackground {(data, error) in
                sportCell.imageMatch.image = error == nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil
                    }
                }
                else if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

                let newIndex = (basketString.count - 1) - indexPath.row
                let basket = basketString[newIndex]
                sportCell.matchLabel.text = basket.matchB
                basketString[newIndex].imagePrB.getDataInBackground {(data, error) in
                    sportCell.imageMatch.image = error == nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil

                }

                }  else if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {

                 let newInt = (tennisString.count - 1) - indexPath.row
                sportCell.matchLabel.text = tennisString[newInt].matchT

                tennisString[newInt].imagePrT.getDataInBackground {(data, error) in
                        sportCell.imageMatch.image = error == nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil

                }

         }



            sportCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

            let date = Date()
            let calendar = Calendar.current



            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
            dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_UA")
            dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true


            if let today = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 0, to: date) {
                let todayString = dateFormatter.string(from: today)
                sportCell.dataSave.text = todayString

            } else if let yesterday = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: date) {
                let yesterdayString = dateFormatter.string(from:yesterday)
                sportCell.dataSave.text = yesterdayString
            } else {
                sportCell.dataSave.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

            }

            sportCell.setNeedsLayout()
            sportCell.layoutIfNeeded()

            return sportCell
 }
```

код парсинга :

```
func loadObjects2() {
    let query = Basketball.query() as! PFQuery<Basketball>

    query.findObjectsInBackground  { (objects, error) in
        if error == nil {


            self.basketString = objects!

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })

        } else {
            print(error!)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Вы же берете для даты `let date = Date()`, вот и показывает актуальное время на момент reload tableView. Нужно дату брать из данных, которые хотите отображать (если она там есть).

Comment: Можете скинуть ссылку на пример? а то я немного не понял.